# Find.() Not working correctly

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Find.() is not finding the correct row. Sometimes it finds a random row other times it finds the first row. This is my Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Tool_Turn_In_Click()
Dim iTurnIn As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Answer As String
'Ask Yes or no
Answer = MsgBox("This will EDIT the invitory. Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
If Answer = vbYes Then
    'Find Row to Edit
    Set ws = Worksheets("ToolData")
        iTurnIn = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.SelectedRow.Value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    'Writing textbox/combobox values to worksheet
    With ws
        .Cells(iTurnIn, 5).Clear 'this is here to Debug
        .Cells(iTurnIn, 5).Value = "Yes"
    End With
    Call CommandButton_SSN_Search_Click
    Call UF1ListBoxRefresh
    MsgBox "Succesfuly EDITED Selected line!"
    Else
    'Do nothing
    End If
    End Sub
```

I have narrowed the problem down to this

```
ws.Cells.Find(iTurnIn = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.SelectedRow.Value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

`Me.SelectedRow` is a TextBox that contains the Row number value of the row I want to edit.

I have another way to do this that works fine but it uses a loop. I would rather know what it is that I'm doing incorrectly and use Find()

Comment: So `SelectedRow` contains a number or a string that you are trying to find.  And are you trying to find that in a specific column?  Also if the value is not found it will cause an error.

Comment: SelectRow is a TextBox that contains a number. Yes this number is in a specific column. It is not throwing an error. It out puts correctly, the problem is that it is not finding the correct row that the number from the textbox is in.

Comment: Which column is the specific column?

Comment: Column E, but would that effect it? It is searching Row by Row to find the cell value or should be.

Comment: It could affect it, because it might find that same number in another cell in another column, especially without the `LookAt:=xlWhole` parameter.  (But if the IDs are in column E, why are you changing the values in column E?)

Comment: I misspoke It is column Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDs are in column E, you should use something like:

```
Dim findResult As Range
Set findResult = ws.Columns("E").Find(What:=Me.SelectedRow.Value, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlWhole)
If findResult Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "ID not found"
    Exit Sub
End If
iTurnIn = findResult.Row
```

Limiting the `Find` to just the `Column` that you believe the value should be in stops false matches against the values in other columns.  And limiting the search to `xlWhole` stops things like `152` being matched with `3152` or `1527`.

Comment: That explains the "randomness" of what I was experiencing before. 'LookAt:=xlWhole' Was exactly what I was needing. Thank you very much for your help.